# Как подключить к элементу управления источник данных находящейся в экземпляре класса, который в свою очередь находится в ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте!
Разрабатываю программу, в которой пользователь сможет подключаться к определённому клиенту (такой же программе) в локальной сети или через сеть Интернет и загружать свои файлы или скачивать имеющиеся. Отображение списка клиентов осуществляется с помощью списка ListBox. В программе это выглядит следующим образом: в *MainViewModel* имеется коллекция *ObservableCollection* элементов типа *RemoteClientViewModel* привязанная к ListBox. *RemoteClientViewModel* в свою очередь является ViewModel'ю для класса модели *RemoteClient*. View в данном случае - элемент списка ListBox.
В окне имеется также ListView для отображения списка файлов удалённого клиента. И в классе *RemoteClientViewModel* по идее должна быть коллекция с информацией об этих файлах: размер, тип, дата изменения и прочее.

Вопрос заключается в том, как подключить эту коллекцию к элементу ListView? При условии, что сама эта коллекция будет находится в экземпляре класса RemoteClientViewModel. А он в свою очередь в коллекции, которая является источником данных для ListBox и находится в MainViewModel.